# Laravel Eloquent Scopes: Select latest record if row column is true, otherwise do not select next latest match and return as false

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have an Eloquent query scope:

```
public function scopeWhereHasStatus(Builder $case, string $status)
{
    return $case->whereHas('statusUpdates', function ($q) use ($status) {
        $q->where('status', $status)->latest();
    });
}
```

This is what my end query looks like using `toSql()`:

```sql
select * from `mediation_cases` where exists (
    select * from `mediation_case_status_updates` 
    where `mediation_cases`.`id` = `mediation_case_status_updates`.`mediation_case_id` 
    and `status` = ? 
    order by `created_at` desc
)
```

In pseudo SQL, what I'm trying to do is:

```sql
select all from "cases" where user_id = ? and has status of ?
```

### Problem

The case statuses are in a separate table because we need to record the status changes. So what I'm trying to do is use a scope to say, "out of all the cases status records, only select the latest status record for that case_id and only if it has the specific status."

The problem is, the where clause function means if the WHERE condition isn't true, it will try for the next record. This means if a case has previously had the status in question, the query will also return true. However, I need it, so it only attempts the where clause on the latest record, and that is it.

### Considerations

I'm aware I could use a DB builder instance within the scope and write this logic in PHP, but that would require passing the case id to the scope function, and this isn't possible for this project. It's also bad for performance, so I would like to do it within one query and within an Eloquent scope for the sake of performance and consistent architecture, if possible.

I'm also aware I could add an `active` column on the status records and new status creation, mark all previous records as false, and set the new one true. But again, I'd prefer to do it in an SQL query without relying on columns, if possible.

---

I really appreciate any help you can provide. I hope this makes sense and is possible to use Eloquent within one query. Been very difficult to Google, as you can imagine.

### Edit for example

If we have a case with ID say 22, here's a list of status updates with case_id 22:

id: 4, case_id: 22, status: in_progress, created_at: 12th July <--- This is the latest and therefore the "current status"

id: 3, case_id: 22, status: imported, created_at: 11th July

id: 2, case_id: 22, status: requires_signing, created_at: 10th July

id: 1, case_id: 22, status: new, created_at: 9th July

Now say I query where "current status" = "requires_signing", the where clause will of course pick out id #2. I need the where clause to only check the latest record.

Comment: What you are describing as your problem, makes no sense: "_the order clause function means if the where condition isn't true, it will try for the next latest record._", that is not true at all, if `where status = ?` and that is false, it will return nothing... What are you actually getting back as a result ? Add example (real testing data, not data created by you here just for understanding it, try your code and show us) data so we can see and understand better what you are getting as a result.

Comment: Please provide a short list of table values, plus the desired output.

Comment: @matiaslauriti  Sorry if it's my wording. The where clause will check all the records sequentially until it finds a match. In my case, I need it to only check the very latest record, if not true, don't attempt to check any other records. Does that make more sense?